# Is there any point in using `sudo` when you are the sole user of your machine?

Tags: security, sudo, su

I'd like to know if there is any reason why I should use `sudo` instead of `su`, taking into account that I am the owner and sole user of my machine (and hence have root access whenever I want). Also, in case there is a good reason to prefer `sudo`, I want to know what privileges should I give myself.

---

**EDIT:** I have just found a very nice reference for `sudo`. If anyone is interested it is [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sudo).

Comment: As the only user `sudo`, through `/etc/sudoers`, gives you quite a lot of fine grained control over when you require passwordless elevated privileges. This mitigates some of the risk around overuse of said elevated privileges. You also use your own environment and settings, not root's.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your answer. I get `sudo` is usefull in a big workspace to restrict what each 'employee' is able to do without asking the administrator. But in my case, since I also own the root password, how can I benefit from it?

Comment: It allows you to methodically determine what comands you will *not* require elevated privileges for; meaning that you are less likely to habitually switch to root and inadvertently break something. Essentially, it is helpful to tailor your setup to meet your needs around privileges, rather than the one-size-fits-all approach that root entails. Ultimately, though, it comes down to personal preference...

Comment: You can decide what environment you want when you run one-off commands more easily than with su.

Comment: Similar question on [security.se]: [Do Simple Linux Servers Really Need a Non-Root User For Security Reasons?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47576/do-simple-linux-servers-really-need-a-non-root-user-for-security-reasons)

Comment: Another similar question: http://superuser.com/questions/662739/using-the-root-account-on-a-single-user-system/662764

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, segregating root privileges protects you from yourself.  If you log in as an unprivileged user, then the worst you can do (without `sudo`) is destroy your own userspace.  Root can potentially destroy everything on the system, any connected drives, and any network connected read-write mounts with a simple `rm -fr /`.

Also, using `sudo` rather than `su` decreases the chances you will `su` up to root, do a thing, and then leave the superuser shell open.

Comment: So that is what they mean when they say `sudo` operates on a per-command-basis: using `sudo` you just run the specific command as root and you're done; you never get to be root (i.e. your prompt never changes from $ to #). Is this right?

Comment: That's exactly correct, notwithstanding `sudo -s`.

Comment: Okay, so it reduces the 'temptation' to become superuser and have unlimited power. In my case, since I am a beginner, I could configure `sudo` to let me run all commands but asking me for authentication each time I invoke it, right?

Comment: The defaiult behavior of `sudo` is to require the user to authenticate the first time it is used, or if a certain amount of time has passes since it was last used.  It is possible to change it to always require a password.  This can be done in `/etc/sudoers` by changing that timeout to zero. Be sure to edit this file using `visudo` and not directly, as if you mess up when editing directly, you cah lock yourself out entirely with a broken `sudoers`.

Comment: Right, so the timeout you mention is the "ticketing system" I read about in the intro to `sudo`. Is it a good practice to change it to zero?

Comment: It comes down to how much you trust yourself.  I'm okay with a five minute timeout, but others prefer to require the implied "Are you sure?" of a password prompt for each and every command.  As with many system settings, it's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Also, `sudo` can be set up (in `sudoers` to allow specific known-safe commands or scripts to be run without password, amongst other things.  `sudo` is something of a swiss army knife to `su`'s lever.

Comment: I think I will do that since I'm just beginning. Thanks for your help, it was extremely useful.

Comment: Also, the use of sudo increases the likelihood that you remain the only user of your computer.